# SQL Server error 1117 while running backup

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, backup

While I was running backup for SAGE DBs, for the first one with a small size, it has finished with no errors while the second one with a bigger size it started and failed on 80% with this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: unable to read on "E:\Data\file_name.mdf":1117 (the request couldn't be performed because of an I/O device error) (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo).

I run the query to empty log file and I tried again the backup, it didn't succeed.

I also ran the command `DBCC CHECKDB`, it showed 0 error.

Anything I should verify ?

Comment: What type of device is `E:`? I  would guess it's not an internal storage device?

Comment: @Larnu Yeah it's a local disk in the same server